# Problemas con cambios entre ramas git

Tags: git

Estaba trabajando con `git`, creando nuevas funcionalidades en ramas diferentes a `master`. Siguiendo este flujo:

- Crear rama desde master con `git checkout -b "nombre-rama"`
- hacer modificaciones sobre archivos
- agregar los archivos modificados con `git add .`
- Realizar el commit
- cambiar a la rama master y repetir los primeros cuatro pasos, pero con una rama diferente.

Ahora bien, lo que sucede es que los cambios que realice en la primer rama, aparecen en la segunda rama. No entiendo muy bien que es lo que sucede, porque en lo que se no deberia pasar. El editor que estoy usando es visual studio code.

Comment: Cierto, no debería pasar. Suena a que en realidad no has regresado a `master`. ¿Cómo estás regresando a `master`?

Comment: Depende un poco de qué quieras decir con "los cambios que realicé en la primera rama aparecen en la segunda rama". Tal vez lo que quieres decir es que, desde la rama nueva, un `git log` aún te muestra commits de la otra rama, lo que puede suceder si usas la opción `--all` (u otras que tienen ese efecto). Sin embargo eso no significa que los commits estén en la rama actual. ¿Puedes mostrar cómo ves que lo están? Y si realmente es como dices, la causa más probable es que la nueva rama es hija de la vieja, en vez de `master`.

Comment: la forma en la que vuelvo a master es con git checkout master, de ahi saco la nueva rama

Comment: haz probado usar gitlens el plugin de VSC?

Comment: No lo he intentado

Answer (score 1):

Intentando recrear una situación parecida, el comportamiento debería ser igual a lo siguiente:

Inicializo git en un directorio con un documento llamado "Documento.txt" cuyo contenido es "Prueba".

```sh
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/Escritorio/carpeta/.git/

$ git add .

$ git commit
[master (root-commit) 6fa6d47] Primer commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 Documento.txt

$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Una vez hecho esto, creo dos ramas, hago modificaciones en cada una y vuelvo a la master al finalizar, de la misma manera que se hace en la pregunta:

```sh
$ git checkout -b "rama1"
Switched to a new branch 'rama1'

$ nano Documento.txt 

$ git add Documento.txt

$ git commit Documento.txt 
[rama1 1892aea] Modificado desde rama1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

$ git checkout master
```

Repito el mismo proceso desde una rama llamada "rama2":

```sh
$ git checkout -b "rama2"
Switched to a new branch 'rama2'

$ nano Documento.txt 

$ git add Documento.txt

$ git commit Documento.txt 
[rama2 a03b3ec] Modificado desde rama2
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

$ git checkout master
```

En este punto, estando situado en la rama "master", realizaré el siguiente comando:

```sh
$ git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate
```

Esto nos muestra el siguiente "grafico" por terminal:

```
* a03b3ec (rama2) Modificado desde rama2
| * 1892aea (rama1) Modificado desde rama1
|/  
* 6fa6d47 (HEAD -> master) Primer commit
```

Lo que nos muestra es que al realizar un `git log --all` podemos ver el árbol completo de commits de nuestro repo. En este caso, la rama master solo tendrá las modificaciones que se han hecho en la rama master, y las ramas "rama1" y "rama2" tendrán únicamente los cambios que se han hecho en cada una de ellas.

Si se realiza únicamente el comando `git log` solo podremos ver los commits de la rama en la que nos encontramos. En este caso (en la master), solo veríamos un commit:

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git log
commit 6fa6d474c453b31998ff7e96ab58988226e01896
Author: d***********f <**********@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Jul 26 13:16:37 2019 +0200

    Primer commit
```

Si desde el mismo punto realizamos `git log --all` veremos todos los commits del repo, pero no significa que esa rama (en este caso la master) contenga dichos commits.

```
$ git log --all
commit a03b3ecaa40631026c58e81be29aa4956fb0e239
Author: d***********f <**********@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Jul 26 13:23:52 2019 +0200

    Modificado desde rama2

commit 1892aea46411dc599f3424ebde66e0033efc7b5a
Author: d***********f <**********@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Jul 26 13:21:37 2019 +0200

    Modificado desde rama1

commit 6fa6d474c453b31998ff7e96ab58988226e01896
Author: d***********f <**********@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Jul 26 13:16:37 2019 +0200

    Primer commit
```